# How to Paste Full Location of an Object in a List (r)

Tags: r, list, object, paste, names

I'm trying to paste the full location of an object in a list but all I can seem to do is paste the name.

For example, if I have a List of objects named A, B, C, and I want to paste the names of those objects I can use:

```
paste0(names(MyList[1:2]),  "%%%", names(MyList[3]))
```

and I'll get

```
A B %%% C
```

but what if I want to paste

```
MyList[["A"]] MyList[["B"]] %%% MyList[["C"]]
```

Is there a `full.names` or something along those lines?

Comment: From ``?`[[` ``:`"[[ can be used to select a single element dropping names, "`. By using `[[` you're deliberately removing names. If you want to keep names, use `[`. Compare: `names(iris[[1]])` with `names(iris[1])`

Comment: @divibisan would you be able to expand this into an answer because although `names(iris[[1]])` and `names(iris[1])` produce different results I'm not sure I follow how I could achieve what I want to as per my original question.

Comment: What do you want to do? I’m actually not sure what the output you want is

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
lapply(1:length(MyList[["A"]]), 
       function(x){paste0(MyList[["A"]][x],
                          MyList[["B"]][x],
                          "%%%",
                          MyList[["C"]][x])})
```